# implicit declaration of function ' Itoa ' is invalid in C99

Tags: c, строки

Когда я пытаюсь использовать ltoa(), выдает такую ошибку. Как ее можно исправить?

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char test[]="999 bottles stand on 2 tables";
char orig[81],result[81],dig[13];
int radix=10;
void main()
{
    char *p;long d;
    strcpy(orig,test);
    p=strtok(test," ");
    while (p != NULL)
    {if ((d=atol(p))==0)
       {strcat(result,p);strcat(result," ");}
    else
       {ltoa(d*2,dig,radix);strcat(result,dig);strcat(result," ");}
    p=strtok(NULL," ");}
    printf("Original:\n%s\nResult:\n%s\n",orig,result);
    getchar();
}
```

Comment: Использовать `sprintf`

Comment: Как это записать в этом коде ? Ошибка появляется ,но другая ,хотя меняю код ,под то как описывается для sprintf в интернете...

Comment: `sprintf(dig, "%d", d*2);`